# 128GB SD card thinks it’s 8GB after being cloned. How can I get it to recognize all of the free space?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, sd-card, raspbian

I had an old 8GB SD card that I was using for my Raspberry Pi 2. I made an image of that 8GB SD card and put it on to a 128GB SD card.

Now when my pi boots with the 128GB sd card and I run `df -hT`, I still see:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ df -hT
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root      ext4      7.1G  6.5G  237M  97% /
```

How can I tell the cloned 128GB SD card, that it is bigger than the 8GB it thinks it is?

Following [phuclv’s comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1631260/sd-card-thinks-it-is-smaller-than-it-is-how-do-i-get-it-to-realize-it-is-larger#comment2491336_1631260) I now see:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo parted /dev/mmcblk0 print free
Model: SD SD (sd/mmc)
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 125GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:
Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
        16.4kB  4194kB  4178kB           Free Space
1       4194kB  273MB   268MB   primary  fat32        lba
2       273MB   125GB   125GB   primary  ext4
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ df -hT
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root      ext4      7.1G  6.5G  247M  97% /
```

So I now have increased the partition size, but how do I increase my mounted `/` directory's size? I would think `/` would be the right size now because I also see:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
mmcblk0     179:0    0 116.5G  0 disk
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0   256M  0 part /boot
└─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0 116.2G  0 part /
```

Comment: run resize2fs to expand it

Comment: @phuclv - thanks I'm not sure how to use that, but it did lead me to the `parted` command and I did increase my partition, but I'm still not seeing that space in `/`.  I updated the question accordingly.  Any further insight is appreciated.

Comment: @phuclv ahh I figured it out.  I just need to run `pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo resize2fs /dev/mmcblk0p2` - I guess after I expanded that with `parted` - thanks for the clue!

Comment: You should convert that last comment into a complete answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by `sudo resize2fs [path_to_storage_device]` now use `parted` this will lead you to partitioning where you can resize.